# Get time in hours and minutes but don't want ':' in middle

Tags: android, datetime

**Here is what I tried:**

```
package com.rupendra.example.myapplication;

import android.icu.util.Calendar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    String hour,minute;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar now=Calendar.getInstance();
        int h=now.get(Calendar.HOUR);
        int m=now.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        String r= Integer.toString(h);
        String s=Integer.toString(m);
        for(int i=2;i>=0;i--)
        {
            hour=hour+r.charAt(i);
        }
        for(int i=2;i>=0;i--)
        {
            minute=minute+r.charAt(i);
        }
        String rev="";
        rev=rev.concat(minute).concat(hour);
    }
}
```

But this didn't work.

**Then I tried this:**

```
package javaapplication40;

import static com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.lib.ExsltDatetime.date;
import static java.lang.ProcessBuilder.Redirect.to;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import static jdk.nashorn.internal.objects.NativeJava.to;

public class JavaApplication40 {

  /**
  * @param args the command line arguments
  */
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    String rev="";

    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
    String r = now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + ":" + 
    now.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    for(int i=4;i>=0;i--)
    {
       rev=rev+r.charAt(i);
    }

    System.out.print(rev);
  }
}
```

I want to get the time in hours and minutes separately in a string without ':' i.e; colon in between.  Please help as I am developing a TIME PIN and the code developed by me is not working please give detailed instruction as I am just a beginner in Android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

then you can use this

```
private String getPassword(int a, int b){
    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
    String newHoursValue = checkZero(now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + a);
    String newMintsValue = checkZero(now.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + b);

    String concat = newHoursValue + newMintsValue;
    char[] concatAsCharsArray = concat.toCharArray();
    StringBuilder password = new StringBuilder();

    for(int i = concatAsCharsArray.length -1 ; i >= 0 ; i--){
        password.append(concatAsCharsArray[i]);
    }

    return password.toString();
}

private String checkZero(int value){
    String valueAsString = String.valueOf(value);
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    if(valueAsString.length() < 2)
        stringBuilder.append("0");
     return stringBuilder.append(valueAsString).toString();
}
}
```

Comment: Can I store the value of  date1.setHours(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    and date1.setMinutes(Calendar.MINUTE); in a string variable ? As i want to match it with the password of app lock.

Comment: yes the method will return the value of hours and mint as format `HOUR:MIN` 
... you want get hours and mint separated ??

Comment: because i want to use the password as reverse of time so to match it with password if the time is 14:21 then password would be its reverse 1241 so how can I do that when I can't reverse it. Please help

Comment: yes sir i want to get hour and minutes separated in a string format as I want to reverse them please help, only hope from your side.

Comment: sir this is not working, and i want hour and minutes separately sir and then concatenate it later in reverse order as I need int hours and int minutes for more operation like adding some integer to it. Hence, i need them separately please help. Thanks

Comment: then you just need to use `Calender.HOUR` and `Calender.MINUTE` as i updated answer ..
if you want return hours as 24-hours then use HOUR_OF_DAY instead HOUR

Comment: i also add how you can reverse them

Comment: sir I have to perform some operation of addition on hours and minutes too then want to reverse it that's why want them separately hours and minutes in a variable. Please do help sir, you are helping in great extent please help me regarding this.

Comment: explain what you want as example to i can help you .. you want make operation + on hours and mints then reverse the result ? 
ex
min = 10 , hour = 2
10 + 2 = 12  then you want output 21 ??

Comment: sir let I have in hours=10 and in minutes=25. then i will take two variable a,b and then use it like hours=10+a and minutes=25+b, the value of a and b will be only in between 0-9, then i want to concatenate hour and minute like for a=2,b=3 hours=12 and minutes =28 so there concatenation will be 1228 and the then its reverse will be 8221

Comment: sir, this works as per my requirement but you passed parameter as (int hour,int min) and while retrieving it i have to pass the value of hour and min, but i want that the hour and min that would be passed as a parameter should be the current hour and current minute i.e it takes argument as current time i.e; current hour current minute rather than I have to pass the value for eg. time is 11:49 so it will take hour =11 and min = 49 and in next minute, min=50.  Like String value=getPassword(current hour,current minute, 5,  6). sir please help we are about to complete sir please and thanks too

Comment: yes sir I exactly want this but here also one problem occured if time is 07:06 it only shows 7:6 means it doesn't shows 0 if in beginning it will show 30 but not 03.

Comment: thanks a lot sir so much obliged can't express my feeling you helped to a great extent. This worked as per my requirement.

Comment: sir i have sent u request in linkedIn,please do accept so that i can reach to u for helps in future https://www.linkedin.com/in/rupendra-singh-b8818910a/

Comment: okay i accepted it you can communicate with me whenever you want.